# Limit of a series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Show that the limit of $x_n$ = 2 such that: $$x_n = 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{2^3} + ... + \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$$

I first wrote out a few terms of the sequence to get a feel for its behavior. I then determined it is increasing $$ 1 \le 1+\frac{1}{2} \le 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} \le ... $$

Unfortunately, this is not rigorous enough to determine increasing behavior. I then attempted to verify that this sequence has a suprimum in $\Bbb R $ by using the definition. Here is where I am confused since I am unable to complete the proof by using the increasing/suprimum definition of a limit.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series

Comment: Hint : A geometric series $1 + a + a^2 +... + a^n + ...$ converges if $|a| < 1$ for the sum $\dfrac{1}{1 - a}$

Answer (score 2):

A bit more intuitively:

The first partial sum of the series, $1$, is halfway between $0$ and $2$. The next sum, $1+\frac12$ is halfway between $1$ and $2$. The third sum, $1+\frac12+\frac14$ is halfway between $1+\frac12$ and $2$. And so on. Each new term takes you to halfway between were you were and $2$. This shows that the sequence

1. never exceeds $2$
2. exceeds any given number below $2$
3. is monotonous

Combined with a few very general statements about limits, you should have enough to conclude.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that
\begin{align*}
x_1 &=1 &= 2-1 \\
x_2 &= 1 + \frac{1}{2} &= 2 - \frac{1}{2} \\
x_3 &= 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} &= 2 - \frac{1}{4} \\
x_{n+1} &= 1 + \dots + \frac{1}{2^n} &= 2 - \frac{1}{2^n}
\end{align*}

Now try to show this rigorously.

Answer (score 0):

You've got the right idea, but you still need to make it explicit and general.

First of all, try showing that for all $n,$ we have $x_{n+1}=x_n+f(n)$ for some function $f.$ (*Hint*: What is $x_{n+1}-x_n$?) Then, to show that the sequence is increasing, you need only show that $f(n)>0$ for all $n.$

As for showing the supremum, you want to show that $x_n<2$ for all $n,$ and that $x_n\to 2.$ This means we need to show that $2-x_n$ is positive for all $n,$ and that $2-x_n\to 0.$ Try to figure out an explicit formula for $2-x_n$ that works for all $n,$ prove that it works, prove that it is always positive, and prove that it vanishes as $n$ increases without bound.

Let me know if you have trouble with any of these steps, and I'll see what I can do to get you "unstuck." Alternately, feel free to bounce your ideas off of me, and I can let you know if you're on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

With $x_n= 1+ \frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1}{4}+ \cdot\cdot\cdot+ \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$, $x_n- 1= \frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1}{4}+ \cdot\cdot\cdot+ \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$.

Now factor out $\frac{1}{2}$ on the right side: $x_n- 1= \frac{1}{2}\left(1+ \frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1}{4}+ \cdot\cdot\cdot+ \frac{1}{2^{n-2}}\right)$.  The quantity inside the parentheses is **almost** S again- it is missing the $\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$ term.

So make it equal to S by adding (and subtracting) $\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$ term.
$x_{n}= 1+ \frac{1}{2}\left(1+ \frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1}{4}+ \cdot\cdot\cdot+ \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}- \frac{1}{2^{n- 1}}\right)$
$x_n= 1+ \frac{1}{2}\left(1+ \frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1}{4}+ \cdot\cdot\cdot+ \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\right)- \frac{1}{2^{n}}= 1+ \frac{1}{2}x_n-\frac{1}{2^{n}}$.

That gives $x_n- \frac{1}{2}x_n= \frac{1}{2}x_n= 1- \frac{1}{2^n}$
and then $x_n= 2\left(1- \frac{1}{2^n}\right)= 2- \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$.

Comment: What is "S"? The first time you ever mention it, it seems that you intended to bring it up previously.